# add all values of a IN clause to an subselect column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to pass all values from an `IN` clause, to a`subselect` from a column.

```
SELECT   distinct
         'Atendimentos' Tipo,
         to_char(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy') Competencia,
         pre.cd_prestador,
         se.cd_setor,
         se.nm_setor,
         (
            select  (count(distinct a2.cd_atendimento)) --* 0.3
            from    atendime a2
                    INNER JOIN PRESTADOR Pre2 ON A2.CD_PRESTADOR = 
                                         Pre2.CD_PRESTADOR
                    left join setor se2 on se2.CD_SETOR = 
                                         a2.cd_setor
            where   to_char(a2.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy') = 
                    to_char(a.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy')
                    and pre2.cd_prestador = pre.cd_prestador --Aqui é o problema
                    and se2.cd_setor = se.cd_setor
            group by to_char(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy')
         ) total
FROM     ATENDIME A
         INNER JOIN PRESTADOR Pre ON A.CD_PRESTADOR = Pre.CD_PRESTADOR
         left join setor se on se.CD_SETOR = a.CD_SETOR
WHERE    to_char(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy') = '08/2018'
         and pre.cd_prestador in (127,3921,1704,28,5048,3118,130,3336,2171,1869,128,132,186)
order by se.cd_setor
```

I need this last column to bring me the overall total of calls.

In the subselect `WHERE` (column with the `"total"` alias), I compare the competency with the external select competency, and the sector with the external select sector.

So far, everything normal.

The problem is the column `prestador`, which is, if only one, just had to stay that way up there.

However, I need the comparison to be made with all values that are passed in the `IN` clause of the external select.

Comment: use rextester with a small sample of data. Then we can help understand the problem more. Link it to question and show what you expect as output - we can run query then and see the output generated to compare/fix it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the subquery is meant to compute a total over the whole result set. If so, then this looks like a typical use case for window functions.

I suspect that your subquery could be replaced with just a window function, as follows :

```
SELECT   distinct
         'Atendimentos' Tipo,
         to_char(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy') Competencia,
         pre.cd_prestador,
         se.cd_setor,
         se.nm_setor,
         count(distinct a2.cd_atendimento) over() total
FROM     ATENDIME A
         INNER JOIN PRESTADOR Pre ON A.CD_PRESTADOR = Pre.CD_PRESTADOR
         left join setor se on se.CD_SETOR = a.CD_SETOR
where    to_char(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy') = '08/2018'
         and pre.cd_prestador in (127,3921,1704,28,5048,3118,130,3336,2171,1869,128,132,186)
order by se.cd_setor
```